# Heavy Armor Proficiency as a Dragonborn Sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I am trying to create a 4e Dragonborn Storm Magic Sorcerer (DEX/CHA) and have chosen the Kapak Draconian subrace. I picked up the optional `Instinctive Flight` racial feature and saw this fun feat:

> #### **Draconian Wings**
>
> **Prerequisite:** Bozak or kapak draconian, Instinctive Flight racial feature
>
> **Benefit**: You ignore the speed penalty for wearing heavy armor, and your altitude limit for Instinctive Flight increases to 2.

**Given this race/class combination, is there a way for me to get proficiency with heavy armors outside of the STR13/CON13 `Armor Proficiency` feats?**

*I realize that making my character some sort of Hybrid (Warlock or Paladin, for example) and taking the Hybrid armor proficiency would give me some heavy armor proficiency relatively quickly, but this would prevent me from pursuing the other character options I want. (Such as the Storm Magic class features or the Lightning Fury paragon path.)*

Comment: Why would you *want* to use heavy armor? The secondary stat your striker damage feature is based on is also your AC-boosting stat when you're a sorceror. You'll have better AC in hide than you will in any other armor except *maybe* plate.

Comment: If you *insist* on grabbing heavy armor than the easiest thing to do is talk to your DM about whether or not you can take Battle Cleric's Lore when you take the Divine Healer MC feat.

Comment: Just curious. I'm having trouble building the flavor of character I want (big surprise, eh?) and the closest I could get was Tempest Sorcerer.

Answer (score 1):

Draconian Wings feat doesn't actually make you move any faster in heavy armor while flying.  All of this is taken from the rules compendium of the WotC DnD subscription, which is up to date.

Speed = Distance you can move with the walk command

Instinctive Flight = Gain "FLY SPEED" 6

Heavy Armor = -1 Penalty to "SPEED"

Flying = Use the walk action, but replace your "SPEED" with your "FLY SPEED"

Heavy armor doesn't effect Fly Speed.  Likewise, items and feats that give you a bonus to "Speed" don't effect "Fly Speed."

You have to take feats and items that effect "Fly Speed" or all movement types specifically.

Dragonmark of the Storm (feat), and Butterfly Sandals (item) are two things that specifically effect Fly Speed.

Also read the rules for Altitude Limit.  Altitude limit does not effect how high you can fly.  It only tells you how high you can be at the end of your turn without falling to the ground, and since Instinctive Flight requires you to land at the end of your turn, Altitude Limit is nearly pointless except for using the crash rules.